# Jquery AJAX POST not passing anything to PHP

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I'm having a problem passing variable using POST method with AJAX.Jquery

Here is my code:

ajaxtest.php

```
<?php 
  $dir = $_POST['dir'];
  $scaned = glob($dir."*",GLOB_ONLYDIR);    
  echo json_encode($scaned);
?>
```

ajaxtest.html

```
<html>
<head>

<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.js"></script>

</head>
<script>

$(document).ready(function(){
$('button[type="button"]').click(function(){
    var dir = 'gals/';
    $.ajax({
        url: "ajaxtest.php",
        type: "POST",
        data: dir,
        success: function(results){
            data = jQuery.parseJSON(results);
            for (var i = 0; i < data.length ; i++) {
                $('#buttonA').after('<br />'+data[i]+'<br />'); 
            };

        }
    })
})

})
</script>
<body>
<br />
<button id="buttonA" type="button">Test button</button>

</body>
</html>
```

This code not working.

**But this one do:** (but not with json)

```
$.post("ajaxtest.php", {dir:dir}, function(results){
        var data = $.parseJSON(results);
        for (var i = 0; i < data.length ; i++) {
            $('#buttonA').after('<br />'+data[i]+'<br />'); 
        }
    })
```

why so?!
What is wrong in my code? please advice!
Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`data` should have the following format:

```
data: {
    'dir': dir
}
```

It doesnt work with json because the success parameter name is wrong. It's not according to the code inside the callback.
Change it from `results` to `data`.

```
var dir = 'gals/';
$.ajax({
    url: "ajaxtest.php",
    type: "POST",
    data: {'dir': dir},
    success: function(data){
        data = jQuery.parseJSON(data);
        for (var i = 0; i < data.length ; i++) {
            $('#buttonA').after('<br />'+data[i]+'<br />'); 
        };

    }
});
```

Comment: you're sending a string, and it doesn't have to be called data.  That's how parameters work, you can call them anything within the parens as long as the function references it correctly.

Comment: @thescientist I know that, he asked why it doesn't work, I answered because the paremeter name is not according to his code.

Comment: huh?  he passes the response in as result, then JSON parses it and assigns it to data.  Then uses data.  Not sure I see what you mean.

Comment: You didnt edited data in second add (otherwise it's my problem remains.)

Answer (score 3):

The difference being that in the non-working example, you are sending a string, and in the working example you are sending an object.  So, send that same object in your non-working example.

```
$.ajax({
    url: "ajaxtest.php",
    type: "POST",
    data: {dir : 'gals/'},
    success: function(results){
        data = jQuery.parseJSON(results);
        for (var i = 0; i < data.length ; i++) {
            $('#buttonA').after('<br />'+data[i]+'<br />'); 
        };

    }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

the url field has a trailing slash that can made it not working
so:

```
url:'mypath/'
```

had to be:

```
url:'mypath'
```